# Kafka error: could not find or load main class kafka.admin.topiccommand

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm on Windows 11 and downloaded and unzipped the files into my chosen directory but getting the following error when trying to run a describe command:

`could not find or load main class kafka.admin.Topiccommand`

Command trying to run:

`kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper SERVER_NAME --topic TOPIC_NAME`

Am I missing something? I am running these commands from the `/bin` directory.

I am trying to create Topic by
`kafka-topics.sh` but I can't create topic in cmd terminal.

Comment: Windows doesn't use shell scripts. Please clarify how you are running bin commands? Did you try the `bin/windows`  scripts instead? And show the exact error (capitalization matters). Also, Kafka doesn't use Zookeeper commander flag anymore, so I suggest reading the official quickstart docs

Comment: The command is working now, the issue was resolved. Thank you for the concern